# How to crop a Drawable image and set it as background for a view?

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable

I am trying to get the wallpaper image and setting it as background for a view.
I used this code to get the wallpaper as `Drawable`.

```
Drawable bg = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDrawable();
```

Now I need to set this drawable as background for my `View`. Its simple as

```
view.setBackground(bg);
```

But this sets the whole wallpaper as background. I want only a particular area(say the top half) to be set for the background. My question is how to crop the `Drawable` to accomplish this task? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable` or write the custom `Drawable` if `InsetDrawable` doesn't work

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

try convert your drawable as bitmap and use setImageBitmap(DrawableAsBitmap)

if you have Drawable as Resource try this:

attributes
    Bitmap bitmap_background;
    int screenWidth = 0;
    int screenHeight = 0;

```
sizeScreen();
bitmap_background = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),   R.drawable.your_resource, screenWidth, screenHeight);
view.setImageBitmap(bitmap_background);

private void sizeScreen() {
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time in answering my question. As I mentioned in the question, I get the Drawable with WallpaperManager. So its not from a resource. I'll try it.

Comment: try convert your drawable from  WallpaperManager as bitmap and use setImageBitmap(DrawableAsBitmap)

Comment: I need to set the drawable as background. Not an image of ImageView.

Comment: you can use an imageView with height = screenHeight and width = screenWidth this let you use image as background. This solution works for me. If you wanna write and explain me more about what you want my email is rosiv.92@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks. I am actually designing a widget and making the configuration activity for it. So here I want to just preview how the widget looks on homescreen. So I draw the widget on an ImageView. Now I wonder how to set the wallpaper as its background. It occupies the whole screen if I set the complete wallpaper. So other configuration elements go out of screen. So I am looking forward to crop the wallpaper and then set it as background.